# Can we name class called "Router" in Modals?

Tags: angular

I am doing my Project with Angular 7 and got a quick question about naming class. 
export class Router {
}

Is this valid name?

Comment: Do you mean because there's already something named [`Router`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router)? It's probably best to avoid that confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If the Router class is specific for something, probably prefix/suffix it with context. If not, then I don't really see a problem aside from it being a tad confusing when you make an instance of it for others.

A good book to read is Clean Code, he goes into how context in names is super important. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

From [angular](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) official documentation

> Do use upper camel case for class names.

it means if you use multiple words, capitalize first letter of each words. For example, if you use two words like 'my class', the class name should be MyClass. As you named it Router, it's absolutely right for class name. Because it has only one word. So, first latter should be uppercase.